# Как изменить язык интерфейса веб-формы, используя C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-webforms, visual-studio-2010

Допустим имеем форму с несколькими лэйблами, кнопочками, радиокнопками, надо реализовать переключение между русским и английским интерфейсом.
Подумав немного, я понял, что не будет же форма переводить с русского на английский и обратно тексты в лэйблах и кнопках, если конечно я сам не напишу такую программу, что было бы и излишним в рамках задания, и непосильным с моим нынешним навыком владения языком.
Значит, подумал я, задача сводится к тому, что бы по событию на кнопке произвести подстановку во все элементы, имеющие свойство Text, текста на соответствующем языке.
И тут же возник вопрос, продиктованный моим невежеством: а как одновременно нескольким объектам, присвоить какие-то значения?

Вот например, событие на радиокнопке:

```
if (имя_контрола.событие == true)  {
имя_контрола.Text = "Бла бла"; 
имя_контрола.Text = "Бла блю";
```

}

Я правильно себе это представляю, ну в плане синтаксиса, и вообще порядка вызова свойств объектов, и задания им значений?
Я например, заметил, что лэйблы имеют свойство Text, но что бы туда не было записано, это содержимое не отображается ни где. А вот, вопреки моим ожиданиям свойства Content не оказалось.

Comment: Прекрасно гуглится по запросу *локализация приложений asp.net*. [Вот][1] к примеру описание на MSDN


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms228208(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Нет, вы делаете неправильно, так не делается.
Тема обширная, но постараюсь объяснить максимально сжато и понятно:
На веб-страницах (на формах в данном случае) к лейблам нельзя просто присваивать текст в разметке. Вам необходимо создать файл ресурсов, который будет включать все надписи, тексты, лейблы на двух языках. Каждому тексту присваивается значение-ключ из файла ресурсов. Причём, в каждом файле должно быть одинаковое число надписей с одинаковыми ключами, но разными значениями (на каждом из языков). 
Файлы ресурсов должны называться одинаково, отличие будет только после точки. Пример: **Labels.ru-RU.resx**, **Labels.en-US.resx**. Файлы должны лежать в одной папке проекта (например, Resources). 
Далее самое интересное. Каждому леблу вы присваиваете ключ из ресурсов с указателем на текст. При загрузке страницы asp.net автоматически покажет ресус на том языке, который указан в текущем потоке (свойство Thread.CurrentThread.Name ). Данное свойство можно менять в коде и тем самым все лейблы будут показывать на другом языке.

Важно: язык потока будет сбрасываться при каждой перезагрузке страницы на язык системы, где запущено приложение, поэтому его надо присваивать при каждой загрузке страницы. Сделать это можно внутри файла Global.asax.

Что такое ресурсы: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms227427(v=vs.100).aspx

Видео, рассказывающее об локализациия: http://www.techdays.ru/videos/1010.html

Также погуглите по ключевым фразам "локализация и глобализация .net приложений" или на аналогичные фразы на английском языке (там подробнее).

Comment: Спасибо за старания, очень подробный ответ, всегда бы так отвечали, как вы =)
Жаль не смогу оценить, очков репутации нет.